# Do you still get CPP/OAS if you live outside Canada

Tags: canada, pension, citizenship

If a Canadian citizen decides to spend retirement years outside Canada, do they still get the full amount for CPP/OAS? or do they need to have residence in Canada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer depends on how long you have worked in Canada, the country in which you are currently residing and the social security agreement between the two.

For **OAS** I think, as long as you've worked at least 20 years in Canada (after the age of 18) you are entitled to the full amount.

For **CPP** It will depend on how many years you've contributed. You have to contribute to the CPP for at least one-third of all the years of your “[contributory period](http://www.servicecanada.gc.ca/eng/services/pensions/cpp/contributions/index.shtml#used)”.

It could be more complex depending on your particular circumstances. For more information: http://www.servicecanada.gc.ca/eng/services/pensions/international/index.shtml

Comment: OAS is 20 years of **residence** after 18.  CPP has no restrictions for pension payments, you're talking about death and survivor benefits.